# iphone create folder outside sandbox

Tags: iphone, directory, jailbreak

I have created an app, built as deb. it's for cydia.

Now I want to create custom folders in path like "/var/mobile/MyDoc", it seems the method I used does not work anymore, the folders can not be created:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:MyDocPath
                                withIntermediateDirectories:YES 
                                attributes:nil 
                                error:nil];
```

Do i need to do anything else to create my custom folders?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you test setting the error parameter and see what error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

This still works for me

```
NSString* DATA_DIR = @"/var/mobile/Library/MyAppName";
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSMutableDictionary* attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSNumber* permission = [NSNumber numberWithLong: 0755];
[attributes setObject:permission forKey: NSFilePosixPermissions];
NSError* error = nil;
if (![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: DATA_DIR 
            withIntermediateDirectories: YES       
                             attributes: attributes 
                                  error: &error]) 
{
    NSLog(@"Unable to create data directory: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```