# Unable to create Directory outside the sandbox for THEOS Tweak

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

I'm making an iPhone tweak using THEOS which hooks to Google Chrome App.
Part of the tweak functions, is to handle downloading and saving files using ASIHTTPRequest/ASINetworkQueue.
The user can choose and set the download destination freely.
This works fine as long as I set the download path to "/tmp" or Google Chrome Documents Folder. When I try to choose a folder other then these, like for instance "/var/mobile/Documents/" I get no permission error:

> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x1f53e230 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Documents, NSUnderlyingError=0x1f53b3d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted

I've looked up this error and tried every other answer suggested here on StackExchange but to no avail.

I'm developing for IOS 6 and I'm including the answers I've read here as links in case you guys think I missed out something:

1 - [How to make a directory iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030054/how-to-make-a-directory-ios)

2 - [iphone create folder outside sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281618/iphone-create-folder-outside-sandbox)

3 - [Cydia App Documents Folder Not Created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065585/cydia-app-documents-folder-not-created)

4 - [Gaining root permissions on iOS for NSFileManager (Jailbreak)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841344/error-permission-denied-when-accessing-ios-filesystem-jailbreak)

The last link refers to running the app as root to access non mobile directories but not sure if this is appropriate since I'm only making a tweak for Chrome.

I hope someone could help me with this issue or point me in the right direction. I'm tearing my hair out.

Here's a common code snippet for creating a directory which just doesn't work for me:

```
NSString* SaveDir = @"/var/mobile/Documents/Test";
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSMutableDictionary* attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSNumber* permission = [NSNumber numberWithLong: 0755];
[attributes setObject:permission forKey: NSFilePosixPermissions];
NSError* error = nil;
if (![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: SaveDir 
            withIntermediateDirectories: YES       
                             attributes: attributes 
                                  error: &error]) 
{
    NSLog(@"Unable to create data directory: %@", error);
}
[attributes release];
```

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Is there a **reason** you need to write outside the sandbox?  Can you not use Chrome's normal sandbox for your needs?

Comment: As I mentioned the tweak has a feature which allows the user to choose the destination folder for the download anywhere within the /var/mobile directory. For instance he/she might want to set the destination to /var/mobile/Documents or /var/mobile/Library/SomeDirectory. 
An example of that is what Safari Download Manager uses if you see what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, I read that part.  The question is **why**?  Why do you need to give a user this ability?  I understand why the user might want to define a whole hierarchy of *relative* folders to put downloads in.  But why is the *absolute* path important?  Why can't all the downloads go somewhere within the sandbox area?  I'm just trying to understand why this problem is worth tearing your hair out over.  Is the point to let the user put some files in locations that will be immediately meaningful to another app?

Comment: Well one reason is myself I have various applications I use for downloading stuff and I like to have them all download to the same location for easy and quick access. The other reason is that I think it would be hard for a standard user to navigate to Chrome sandbox unless for example he has iFile installed and enables the option to show applications names instead of the app's install path

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll say that that it's not hard for a standard user to navigate to the Chrome sandbox.  If you present a file picker dialog, then you can open it programmatically at the Chrome documents or caches root.  They wouldn't have to navigate through `/var/mobile/Applications/*/` to get there.  But, I see now what you're shooting for.

Comment: Update:
I've noticed that for example Safari Download Manager relies on Sandcastle2 to access any directory from a sandboxed app.
Can someone show me how to use this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My note about Cocoanuts Sandcastle from bigboss was right.
I've linked to Sandcastle dylib and using its methods I was able to create files/directories outside the sandbox.

Another library is H2Co3 [Unbox](https://github.com/H2CO3/Unbox), which allows to do the same thing only difference is within unbox commands are executed by daemon.